# NHibernate Fluent - Multiple databases configuration

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, autofac

I am using Fluent Nhibernate from: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to have multiple configuration for different database (different connection string)

```
            builder.Register(c =>
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(DatabaseConfiguration)  // <-- Connection string 1
                .Mappings(AutoMapping.Configurations)
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("connection.isolation", "ReadCommitted"))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty(Environment.CommandTimeout, c.Resolve<IConfig>().SqlCommandTimeoutSeconds.ToString()))
                .BuildConfiguration())
            .SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(c =>
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(ReportingDatabaseConfiguration) // <-- Connection string 2
                .Mappings(AutoMapping.Configurations)
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("connection.isolation", "ReadCommitted"))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty(Environment.CommandTimeout, c.Resolve<IConfig>().SqlCommandTimeoutSeconds.ToString()))
                .BuildConfiguration())
            .SingleInstance();

  builder.Register(c =>
            c.Resolve<Configuration>()
                .BuildSessionFactory())
            .SingleInstance();
```

This configuration is in Autofac.

The current behavior is the later will override the first configuration.

My expected outcome is ISession should be able to know which Database to use depending on the entity I am querying.

Is this possible ?

**Note**: I have tried the solution mentioned in http://devstoolbox.altervista.org/multiple-connections-using-nhibernate/
 but does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having nhibernate to find out what connection (Session) to use based on the entity might not be possible or even a very good idea. What if you join two entities of different dbs. what would be the expected outcome?

What if you request the "right" session in your repo- or query class? You should have the context, on what db you expect the query to run in this class. right?

You Register a NH-Connection-Class that will return a configurable NHibernate SessionFactory

```
public class NHConnection
{
 private string _connectionString;
 private Type _markerType;

 public WithConnectionString(string connectionString)
 {
  _connectionString = connectionString;
  return this;
 }

 public NHConnection UseMarkerAssembly(Type markerAssembly)
    {
        _markerType = markerAssembly;
        return this;
    }

 public ISessionFactory Build()
 {
   var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(_connectionString) // <-- Connection string 2

            //.Mappings(AutoMapping.Configurations) consider using a configurable markerAssembly for each db like:
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(markerType.Assembly)
            });

            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("connection.isolation", "ReadCommitted"))
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty(Environment.CommandTimeout, c.Resolve<IConfig>().SqlCommandTimeoutSeconds.ToString()))
            .BuildConfiguration());
    return config.BuildSessionFactory();
 }
}

 //Register the FactoryBuilder in your Autofac Module

 builder.Register(x => new NHConnection().WithConnectionString("your;connectionString:toDb1").UseMarkerAssembly(typeof(MarkerTypeAssemblyForDB1Mappings)).Build()).Keyed<ISessionFactory>("db1").SingleInstance();
 builder.Register(x => new NHConnection().WithConnectionString("your;connectionString:toDb2").UseMarkerAssembly(typeof(MarkerTypeAssemblyForDB2Mappings)).Build()).Keyed<ISessionFactory>("db2").SingleInstance();
 builder.Register<Func<string, ISessionFactory>>(c =>
        {
            IComponentContext co = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return db => co.ResolveKeyed<ISessionFactory>(db);
        });     


 // Resolve the factory for DB 1, 2 or 3 in your query / repo class      

 public class QueryClass{
   private _factoryLookUp Func<string, ISessionFactory> FactoryLookup { get; set; }
   public void QueryClass(Func<DataDomain, ISessionFactory> factoryLookup)
   {
    _factoryLookUp = factoryLookup; 
   }

   public executeYourQuery()
   {
     using(var session = factoryLookup("db1").OpenSession)
     {
       ....
     }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Well explained and this does make sense to me.

I was hoping to resolve the session initialization in Autofac rather than in each of the repo classes.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I hear you. You can always work with a BaseRepBb1, and BaseRepoDb2 to hide the setup